# How to remove certain directories from lcov code coverage report?

Tags: bash, shell, lcov

I'm not too strong with using lcov and shell scripting so it's a learning process for me. I understand the basics of making a code coverage report but I don't know the line of code to exclude certain directories. In a shell executable file I wrote the following code:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    ROOT_DIR=$1
    DEST_DIR=$2
    TARGET_DIR=$3
    TARGET=$4

   #init lcov
   lcov -c -i -d $TARGET_DIR/.. -o $TARGET_DIR/cov_init.info

    #run unit test executable
    "$DEST_DIR/$TARGET"

     #capture coverage after running executable
     lcov -c -d $TARGET_DIR/.. -o $TARGET_DIR/cov_test.info

     #I added this in-generate delta of coverage
     lcov -a $TARGET_DIR/cov_init.info -a $TARGET_DIR/cov_test.info -o $TARGET_DIR/cov.info

  # I added this in- Excludes some third party code
                    lcov --remove $TARGET_DIR/cov.info '/opt/*' '/usr/*' '$ROOT_DIR/Common?ExternalLibraries/*'

  #I added this in-generate report
            genhtml $TARGET_DIR/cov.info --ignore-errors source --output-directory $DEST_DIR/CoverageReport/$TARGET
            xdg-open $DEST_DIR/CoverageReport/$TARGET/index.html &
```

I'm pretty sure I need to exclude the directories before I capture the coverage after running executable.

Comment: Modern lcov's (>=1.14) has --exclude. See http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/lcov.1.php.

Answer (score 28):

[`lcov`](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/lcov.1.php) has an option `--remove` to ignore coverage data for specified files.

> `--remove tracefile pattern`
>
> Remove data from `tracefile`.
>
> Use this switch if you want to remove coverage data for  a  par-
>               ticular  set  of files from a `tracefile`. Additional command line
>               parameters will be interpreted as shell wildcard patterns  (note
>               that  they  may  need  to  be escaped accordingly to prevent the
>               shell from expanding them first).  Every file entry in tracefile
>               which matches at least one of those patterns will be removed.
>
> The  result of the remove operation will be written to stdout or
>               the `tracefile` specified with `-o`.
>
> Only one of  `-z`, `-c`, `-a`, `-e`, `-r`, `-l`, `--diff` or `--summary` may  be
>               specified at a time.

You can do something like; quoting from the hyper-link below

```
lcov --remove /tmp/libreoffice_total.info -o /tmp/libreoffice_filtered.info \
    '/usr/include/*' \
    '/usr/lib/*' \
    '/usr/local/src/libreoffice/*/UnpackedTarball/*' \
    '/usr/local/src/libreoffice/workdir/*' \
    '/usr/local/src/libreoffice/instdir/*' \
    '/usr/local/src/libreoffice/external/*' \
```

Refer to [this page](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Lcov) for more documentation.

Comment: this might be a dumb question but how come you have in single quotes '/usr/mydirToExclude/*' and how does that relate to the code /tmp/mylibfiletoExclude.info ?

Comment: Refer the embedded link for actual example!

Comment: @I_love_coding_93: Were you able to use the option for your need?

Comment: Did you go through this link, https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Lcov#Remove_.2F_filter_out_remaining_unwanted_stuff_from_tracefil, If I understand right, removing directories from code coverage report is what you wanted

Comment: @I_love_coding_93, yes @Inian shows to you how to remove coverage data from existed report and put coverage data in new (filtered) report. Other way to do the similar is use `extract` option.

Comment: @I_love_coding_93, just put your and @Inian code together: `lcov -c -d $TARGET_DIR/.. -o $TARGET_DIR/cov_test.info && lcov --remove $TARGET_DIR/cov_test.info '/usr/include/*' -o $TARGET_DIR/cov_test_filtered.info`.

Comment: @Gluttton: Appreciate your comments!

Comment: @Inian how comes single quotes are being used instead of double quotes for the directories like '/usr/include/*' -o $TARGET_DIR/cov_test_filtered.info

Comment: @I_love_coding_93: Why is that a problem when `lcov` treats it such a way? All you need to get is, if the option is helping you solve the problem as expected right?

Comment: Please note that --remove is a separated option which cannot be combined with --capture, so one needs to capture the data first, then call lcov --remove on it and only then generate HTML.